# How do I display text from another window in windows form c#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

The goal is to display the text from user input using radio button and combo box. I'm using Visual Studio, by the way.

This is the code from the first window:

```
private void btn_apply_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    firstName = tbx_firstName.Text;
    middleName = tbx_middleName.Text;
    lastName = tbx_lastName.Text;
    completeName = firstName + " " + middleName + " " + lastName + " ";

    gender = lbl_gender.Text;
    level = lbl_level.Text;
    status = lbl_status.Text;


    if (rbtn_male.Checked)
    {
        lbl_gender.Text = rbtn_male.Text.ToUpper();
    }

    else
    {
        lbl_gender.Text = rbtn_female.Text.ToUpper();
    }

    //Level

    if (rbtn_gradeEleven.Checked)
    {
        lbl_level.Text = rbtn_gradeEleven.Text.ToUpper();
    }

    else if (rbtn_gradeTwelve.Checked)
     {
        lbl_level.Text = rbtn_gradeTwelve.Text.ToUpper();
    }

    else if (rbtn_iST.Checked)
    {
        lbl_level.Text = rbtn_iST.Text.ToUpper();
    }

    else if (rbtn_iSM.Checked)
    {
        lbl_level.Text = rbtn_iSM.Text.ToUpper();
    }

    else
    {

    }

    //Admission Status

    cbx_status.SelectedItem.ToString();


    //Form2

    this.Hide();
    Form2 output = new Form2();
    output.Show();
```

Meanwhile, this is the code for the second window (Result):

```
private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lbl_displayName.Text = Form1.completeName;
    lbl_displayGender.Text = Form1.gender;
    lbl_displayLevel.Text = Form1.level;
    lbl_displayStatus.Text = Form1.status;
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: when `Form2` should display elements from `Form1`, the former surely has to have a reference to the latter. So start giving `Form2` a reference to your `Form1`-instance, e.g. using a constructor-arg on `Form2`.

Comment: May I know if you have got any chance to check the answers? I am glad to help if you have any others questions. If it can solve your issue, you could click '✔' to mark it as an answer to change its status to Answered.

Comment: Hello, I figured that the root problem lies in  passing the form in gender & level so I called form 2 to form 1 whereas the comments focused on restarting a program with different approach though it helped me figure out the root problem! @JingmiaoXu-MSFT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
Form2 output = new Form2();
output.Show();
```

To:

```
Form2 output = new Form2();
output.Show(this); // <-- Form1 as the Owner of output
```

Now in Form2, simply cast `.Owner` back to Form1:

```
private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form1 f1 = (Form1)this.Owner;
    lbl_displayName.Text = f1.completeName;
    lbl_displayGender.Text = f1.gender;
    lbl_displayLevel.Text = f1.level;
    lbl_displayStatus.Text = f1.status;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

when `Form2` should display elements from `Form1`, the former surely has to have a reference to the latter. So start giving `Form2` a reference to your `Form1`-instance, e.g. using a constructor-arg on `Form2`.

However usually you don't want to pass **controls or forms** around, but just specific **values** within those. In your case those are the `gender`, `name` the `level` and the `status`. So just provide those arguments to `Form2`, not the entire `Form1`-instance:

```
class Form2 : Form
{
    private readonly string name; // ...
    public Form2(string name, string status, string level, string gender)
    {
        this.name = name;
        // ...
    }
}
```

Now you can easily access those variables within your `Load`-event:

```
private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lbl_displayName.Text = this.name;
    lbl_displayGender.Text = this.gender;
    lbl_displayLevel.Text = this.level;
    lbl_displayStatus.Text = this.status;
}
```